# why isn't django finding my "properly" named templates folder?

Tags: python, django, modelform

In [this tutorial](http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html), there is a `ModelForm`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["post"]

def add_comment(request, pk):
    """Add a new comment."""
    p = request.POST

    if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
        author = "Anonymous"
        if p["author"]: 
            author = p["author"]

        comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
        cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
        cf.fields["author"].required = False

        comment = cf.save(commit=False)
        comment.author = author
        comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.blog.views.post", args=[pk]))
```

Where are they getting comment `comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))` from? How can there already by a comment if we haven't made it or saved it yet, and the whole purpose of the function is to "add_comment"? If it already existed, I don't see why we'd be adding it again. Thanks

Comment: The title mentioned template folders, where exactly is the question from the title?

Comment: Note that the [tutorial you linked to](http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/index.html) is for Django 1.1 and 1.2, so is very out of date. There appears to be an [updated version](http://www.lightbird.net/dbe2/) that claims to work with Django 1.7.

Comment: I don't understand what your title has to do with the question.

Comment: I was posting a different question, the title is an accident. The question is correct though. I solved the issue that the title was based on, and I cannot see where to edit the title here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't getting a comment from the db, it's [creating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) a new comment instance.

```
comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
```

It might be easier to understand if we rewrite it more verbosely:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk) # fetch the post based on the primary key
comment = Comment(post=post) # create a new comment (it is not saved at this point)
...
comment.save() # the comment is saved to the db
```